# Nothing to be done for 'program1' . Trying to open a Ruby program using MAKEFILE

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use a makefile to run different programs, each program is located in a subdirectory of the makefile.

When I type `make program1` the Ruby program (located in the directory 'program1') should run. When I type `make program2` (located in the directory 'program2') the Python program will run.

Here is the MAKEFILE:

```
.PHONY: program1 program2
HOST=localhost
DATABASE=student
USER=root
export HOST DATABASE USER PASSWORD
program1:
    ruby program1/program1.rb $(HOST) $(DATABASE) $(USER) $(PASSWORD)
program2:
    ...
```

The problem is that when I try to run program1, the output is:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'program1'.
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a Ruby problem.

Comment: this is not a ruby problem.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't the task that make is most suited towards.

If you want to use make for this sort of 'run a task' activity you want something like what the GNU make manual discusses in the [Empty Target Files to Record Events](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Targets) section.

> 4.8 Empty Target Files to Record Events
>
> The empty target is a variant of the phony target; it is used to hold recipes for an action that you request explicitly from time to time. Unlike a phony target, this target file can really exist; but the file’s contents do not matter, and usually are empty.
>
> The purpose of the empty target file is to record, with its last-modification time, when the rule’s recipe was last executed. It does so because one of the commands in the recipe is a touch command to update the target file.
>
> The empty target file should have some prerequisites (otherwise it doesn’t make sense). When you ask to remake the empty target, the recipe is executed if any prerequisite is more recent than the target; in other words, if a prerequisite has changed since the last time you remade the target. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> print: foo.c bar.c
>         lpr -p $?
>         touch print
> ```
>
> With this rule, ‘make print’ will execute the lpr command if either source file has changed since the last ‘make print’. The automatic variable ‘$?’ is used to print only those files that have changed (see Automatic Variables).

Though, since your task isn't strictly controlled by changes to any other (prerequisite) files you likely want to use a [Phony Target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) instead.

Your "error" is that you are using a target named the same as a directory you have in your directory so make sees that directory and a rule that doesn't give make any reason to need to rebuild it (no prequisites) and so make says that it has "nothing to do".